# Problems when running MAX aggregate query in Postgres (Redshift) with two select columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run this simple query on a Redshift table:

```
select
    max(id),
    created_date
    from records.access_monitoring
    where created_date < to_timestamp('2020-05-19 16:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

This simply gives the maxmimum value of ID for dates before '2020-05-19 16:00:00'.
This query works fine when I run it against the MySQL table, but however, the same table I have in Redshift, gives this error:

> Invalid operation: column "access_monitoring.created_date" must appear
> in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

But if run the query in Redshift without selecting `created_date` it works fine:

```
select
      max(set_id)
    from records.access_monitoring
    where created_date < to_timestamp('2020-05-19 16:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Is this a Postgres related issue or Redshift specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should not work in MySQL either, because you have an aggregation query with no `group by` and unaggregated columns.  The query is malformed.

Instead, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id, created_date
from records.access_monitoring
where created_date < '2020-05-19 16:00:00'
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

This should work in either database.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I ran it against MySQL (Aurora) and it actually worked. Makes sense it shouldn't but it did. Thank you.
Just to make sure, the order by clause should be ```id```, correct? Since i want the max(id)?

Comment: @madu . . . Older versions of MySQL allowed that syntax, returning an arbitrary `created_date`.  And yes . . . I misread the logic.  The `order by` should be by `id`.